# Connecting JSON Data to ListView using Sqlite and Adapter respectively

Tags: android, json, listview, android-sqlite, android-adapter

I am trying to make an application that lists related books data after typing isbn on EditText(**edx**). EditText works properly with JSON part (**GetBookInfo**) in Entrance.java. Before implementing **sqlite**, the app could show on the listView properly. However the item on the list disappeared when i restarted the app. To solve this problem, I decided to use **Sqlite Database** I tried connecting **GetBookInfo** to my **Sqlite Database** and also the database to **BookAdapter** Although the app works, when i enter an isbn, nothing happens. The list seems empty. I think i could not connect parts with each other properly.

**Planned Path**:My isbn -> edx(EditText) -> GetBookInfo(Json Part and it works) -> Database (sqlite method and maybe the problem is here) -> BookAdapter -> ListView

When i extract the database part and change `db.bookAdd(book)` -at the end of GetBookInfo() part- with `booksList.add(book)` and add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`everything is alright. Any isbn i enter in edx is listing proberly but it dissapear when i restart the app. i want to store it using sqlite.

**Book.java**

```
public class Books {

private String title;
private String author;

public Books() {

}

//Getters and setters
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}
public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}
```

}

**BookAdapter.java**

```
public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Books> {
private final Context context;
private ArrayList<Books> bookList;


LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder = null;


public BookAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Books> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    bookList = objects;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return bookList.size();
}

@Override
public Books getItem(int position) {
    return bookList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);

        holder.bookTITLE = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.book_title);
        holder.bookAUTHOR = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.book_author);

        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    holder.bookTITLE.setText(bookList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.bookAUTHOR.setText(bookList.get(position).getAuthor());

    return v;
}


static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView bookTITLE;
    public TextView bookAUTHOR;
}
```

}

**Database.java** - my sqlite database

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

BookAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<Books> books;

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sqllite_database";

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "book_list";
private static String BOOK_NAME = "book_name";
private static String BOOK_AUTHOR = "author";

private static final String[] COLUMNS = {BOOK_NAME,BOOK_AUTHOR};

public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    adapter = new BookAdapter(context, R.layout.row_listitem, books);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + BOOK_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + BOOK_AUTHOR + " TEXT,";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);



}

public void bookDelete(int id){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, BOOK_NAME + " = ?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    db.close();
}

public void bookAdd(Books book) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(BOOK_NAME, book.getTitle());
    values.put(BOOK_AUTHOR, book.getAuthor());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    db.close();
}

public Books getBook(int id){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =
            db.query(TABLE_NAME,
                    COLUMNS,
                    " id = ?", 
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
                    null,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null);

    // 3. if we got results get the first one
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Books book = new Books();

    book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
    book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return book;
}

public ArrayList<Books> getAllBooks() {
    ArrayList<Books> books = new ArrayList<>();

    // 1. build the query
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;

    // 2. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
    Books book = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            book = new Books();

            book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));

            // Add book to books
            books.add(book);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.d("getAllBooks()", books.toString());

    // return books
    return books;
}



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

**Entrance.java** - my main activity

```
public class Entrance extends AppCompatActivity {



ListView bookListView;

ArrayList<Books> booksList = new ArrayList<Books>();
BookAdapter adapter;

private EditText edx;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    Database db = new Database(this);

    bookListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bookListView);
    adapter = new BookAdapter(Entrance.this, R.layout.row_listitem, booksList);
    bookListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    bookListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    booksList=db.getAllBooks();

    edx.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                                          if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                                              String bookSearchString = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=ISBN:" + edx.getText().toString();
                                              new GetBookInfo().execute(bookSearchString);
                                              edx.setText("");
                                              return true;
                                          }
                                          return false;
                                      }
                                  }
    );

}


private class GetBookInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    //fetch book info
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... bookURLs) {
        //request book info


        StringBuilder bookBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String bookSearchURL : bookURLs) {
            //search urls

            HttpClient bookClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
                //get the data
                HttpGet bookGet = new HttpGet(bookSearchURL);
                HttpResponse bookResponse = bookClient.execute(bookGet);
                StatusLine bookSearchStatus = bookResponse.getStatusLine();
                if (bookSearchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    //we have a result
                    HttpEntity bookEntity = bookResponse.getEntity();
                    InputStream bookContent = bookEntity.getContent();
                    InputStreamReader bookInput = new InputStreamReader(bookContent);
                    BufferedReader bookReader = new BufferedReader(bookInput);
                    String lineIn;
                    while ((lineIn = bookReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        bookBuilder.append(lineIn);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return bookBuilder.toString();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        try {

            Database db = new Database(Entrance.this);

                Books book = new Books();
                StringBuilder authorBuild = new StringBuilder("");
                StringBuilder isbnBuild = new StringBuilder("");

                JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray bookArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("items");
                JSONObject bookObject = bookArray.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject volumeObject = bookObject.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");

                book.setTitle(volumeObject.getString("title"));

                JSONArray authorArray = volumeObject.getJSONArray("authors");
                for (int a = 0; a < authorArray.length(); a++) {
                    if (a > 0) authorBuild.append(", ");
                    authorBuild.append(authorArray.getString(a));
                    book.setAuthor(authorBuild.toString());
                }

            db.bookAdd(book);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //no result
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

}

---

#### Edit after comment :-

> So use basic debugging methodologies to determine where the issue
>   isDebug Your App. I'd start with trying to ascertain if there is or
>   isn't anything to display e.g. how many elements are there in
>   bookslist if none then find out why, if there are then why aren't they
>   being displayed by the listview etc

I got this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList shelf.lib.Database.getAllBooks()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: where are you parsing out the json data? I see the string for json, but I dont see where you getting a jsonobject and setting it to your model inorder to get it.

Comment: ' edx.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
  if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
 String bookSearchString = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=ISBN:" + 
 edx.getText().toString();
 new GetBookInfo().execute(bookSearchString);
 edx.setText("");
 return true;
  }
                                          return false;
                                      }
                                  }
    );'

Comment: Perhaps `new GetBookInfo().execute(bookSearchString);
                                              edx.setText("");` should be `edx.setText(new GetBookInfo().execute(bookSearchString));`

Comment: Actually there is no problem related to this part. it is fuctioning well. Before implementing sqlite, getbookinfo() could parse related json data and could show on the listView. I tried to apply sqlite to store data and get permenant list items. I think the problem is in the database part or its connection with book adapter or entrance.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is

- 1) Getting the ListView via it's id.
- 2) Setting up the adpater to be used for the Listview specifying an **empty** ArrayList i.e bookslist. (This, amongst other things, **sets the data to be adapted**).
- 3) Tie the adapter to the ListView. (This displays the list as per the adapter i.e. nothing as **bookslist is empty**).
- 4) Set the ChoiceMode of the LisView. (This is irrelevant)
- 5) Populate the bookslist (too late the ListView is showing the booklist (nothing) it was passed).

In short 5 should be before 2 as it's 3 that result's in the ListView being displayed according to the adapter.

So changing :-

```
bookListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bookListView);
adapter = new BookAdapter(Entrance.this, R.layout.row_listitem, booksList);
bookListView.setAdapter(adapter);
bookListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
booksList=db.getAllBooks();
```

to :-

```
bookListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bookListView);
booksList=db.getAllBooks(); //<<<<< LINE MOVED TO HERE
adapter = new BookAdapter(Entrance.this, R.layout.row_listitem, booksList);
bookListView.setAdapter(adapter);
bookListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Will likely fix that issue.

You additionally have another issue in that getAllBooks issue a NPE due to books being set to null followed by an attempt to add to this now null object.

As such I believe the following will fix this issue :-

```
public ArrayList<Books> getAllBooks() {
    ArrayList<Books> books = new ArrayList<>();

    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Books book = null; // <<<< COMMENTED OUT
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            book = new Books();
            book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));

            // Add book to books
            books.add(book);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    Log.d("getAllBooks()", books.toString());

    // return books
    return books;
}
```

*Note! the above is in-principle code, it has not been tested, so may contain minor errors (there again all that has been done is to comment out a line)*

---

## EDIT

The code is riddled with errors, the above two as pointed out among those. The following is an adaptation that works as far as the ListView is concerned.

In run sequence the errors are :-

## 1.

The Table definition in **Database.java** will cause an SQL Exception as the very last character is a comma, indicating that another column definition will follow, one does not. The character should instead be a closing parenthesis to close the column list.

Instead of :- `+ BOOK_AUTHOR + " TEXT,";` it should be `+ BOOK_AUTHOR + " TEXT)";`

## 2(a).

In the `getBook` method in **Database.java** checking for a null Cursor is useless and exposes the subsequent use of the Cursor `getString` method(s) to fail with an exception should there be no rows in the Cursor (An empty Cursor IS NOT NULL). 
As you are using the `moveToFirst` method then you can make use of it returning true if the move was successfully made (else false).

### 2(b).

You then (and subsequently) try to access the column that has an offset of 2. There is no such column. Column offsets are 0 for the first column and 1 for the 2nd column (and so on). Such errors, which are very common, can be avoided by using the `getColumnIndex(column_name_as_string)` method.

As such

```
// 3. if we got results get the first one
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

Books book = new Books();

book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));

cursor.close();
db.close();

return book;
```

Could be replaced with :-

```
    // CHANGED TO USE :-
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        book.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BOOK_NAME)));
        book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BOOK_AUTHOR)));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return book;
```

### 2(c)

Like and as mentioned in 2(b) the same misuse of column offsets appears in the `getAllBooks` method of **Database.java**. This could instead be :-

```
    // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Books book = new Books();
            //book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            //book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2)); // Error 004 2 columns = offsets 0 and 1 2 out of bounds
            book.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BOOK_NAME)));
            book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BOOK_AUTHOR)));
            books.add(book);
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ERROR 007 refer to 006
    }
```

### 3

For some reason you instantiate an instance of the BookAdapter class and then later use the notifyDataSetChanged method upon that adapter. That will do absolutely nothing of use. **It WILL NOT BE the adapter used for the ListView.** Furthermore even if it were it would do nothing as it is the resultant ArrayList of books that is specified as the source of the adapter.

As such the following code (2 parts)  could be used (i.e. the useless/obfuscating code has been commented out) :-

```
public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    //adapter = new BookAdapter(context, R.layout.row_listitem, books); ERROR 006 completely different adapter
}

see 2(c) for the 2nd part of code that has been commented out.
```

### 4

See the initial answer for the code that gets the ListView source data prior to applying it to the adapter.

---

## Result from working and tested code:-

The following is a screen shot showing that the above changes result in display the ListView :-

[image]

The data was added (run twice so 2 sets of data) using the following code (added to **Entrance.java**) :-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    edx = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    Database db = new Database(this);
    Books book1 = new Books();        //<<<<ADDED FOR TESTING
    book1.setAuthor("Joe Bloggs");    //<<<<ADDED FOR TESTING
    book1.setTitle("The Book!!!");    //<<<<ADDED FOR TESTING
    Books book2 = new Books();        //<<<<ADDED FOR TESTING
    book2.setTitle("Another Book");   //<<<<ADDED FOR TESTING
    book2.setAuthor("A.N Other");     //<<<<ADDED FOR TESTING
    db.bookAdd(book1);                //<<<<ADDED FOR TESTING
    db.bookAdd(book2);                //<<<<ADDED FOR TESTING 

    booksList=db.getAllBooks(); // ERROR 008 MOVED so booklist is populated
    bookListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bookListView);
    adapter = new BookAdapter(Entrance.this, R.layout.row_listitem, booksList);
    bookListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    bookListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: Thank you in advance but nothing has changed. what about the database part and its connections?

Comment: So use basic debugging methodologies to determine where the issue is[Debug Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html). I'd start with trying to ascertain if there is or isn't anything to display e.g. how many elements are there in bookslist if none then find out why, if there are then why aren't they being displayed by the listview etc.

Comment: I got this:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList shelf.lib.Database.getAllBooks()' on a null object reference

Comment: The answer has been amended accordingly. If this does result in the NPE issue being resolved then you should mark this question as being answered. If you have a subsequent issue then you should ask a new question. In future you should undertake basic debugging, if including a stack trace, you should include the stack trace in full within the question. I have updated your question accordingly in this instance.

Comment: The apk is crashed after i edit the code according to your suggestion. Therefore, nothing is resolved yet.

Comment: The answer has been updated with all the code corrections.